Get lowest value in each category
I have a very flat table that is a collection of swimmer names, distances, events (strokes), and times(float). What I would like is to get the only fastest time for each combination of distance and stroke. To be clear, there are multiple distances and multiple strokes (50 free, 100 free, 200 free, 50 back, 100 back .. and so on)
The data looks like the following where the "bold" names would be the records I want returned.



NAME
DISTANCE
STROKE_ID
TIME




Susane Smith
50
1
74.33


Cassey Putnam
50
1
107.24


Kelly Maine
50
1
118.08


Susane Smith
100
1
168.4


Charlotte Castle
200
1
476.46


Susane Smith
50
2
83.23


Charlotte Castle
50
2
104.83


Katy Cooper
50
2
167.49


Susane Smith
100
2
174.93


Charlotte Castle
100
2
219.29


JoAnne Cooper
100
2
355.74


Maddy Franks
200
2
377.15


JoAnne Cooper
200
2
733.77


Charlotte Castle
50
3
138.5


Charlotte Castle
100
3
349.2


Charlotte Castle
200
3
676.12




Great that you showed sample data and your requirements, but you haven't shown any work or any specific issue. Please edit to show the desired output, along with your attempt, output issues, errors, etc.

SO is not a free coding service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include sample data, the output you want to obtain from that data, and the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question about that code.

Very fair feedback. I wasn’t really looking for a solution so much as a “kick” in the right direction. I’ve used some combinations of “distinct” with “min()” and “group by” but as I said .. I’m out of my depth.
I can solve it using brute force coding (node.js) while I try to better my SQL skills. And by “better” I mean “get some”.
Thanks!

I created a table exactly like yours, entered the data and fooled around and got to the following query:
SELECT NAME, DISTANCE, STROKE_ID, TIME FROM (
    SELECT NAME, DISTANCE, STROKE_ID, TIME, ROW_NUBMER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY DISTANCE, STROKE_ID ORDER BY TIME
    ) AS rn FROM <table name here>)
SUB WHERE rn = 1;

Lets break this down step by step:
The query exists of two parts, the outer query and the inner query. First we'll look at the inner query.
(SELECT NAME, DISTANCE, STROKE_ID, TIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY DISTANCE, STROKE_ID ORDER BY TIME
) AS rn FROM <table name here>) SUB

This query adds an extra column to the data called 'rn'. This column is based on the DISTANCE paired with the STROKE_ID. Each different combination of the two gets a new number. So the combinations might look like this:



DISTANCE
STROKE_ID
nr




50
1
1


50
2
2


100
1
3


100
2
4



etc. It then sorts these results ascending by time. Mind that the data I showed above is not the actual newly created table, it just goes to show what the 'rn' column does. Then this new 'table' gets the alias SUB (short for subquery).
Then the outer query:
SELECT NAME, DISTANCE, STROKE_ID, TIME FROM SUB WHERE rn = 1;

The outer query selects the NAME, DISTANCE, STROKE_ID and TIME from SUB where rn = 1. We choose 1 for rn because this is the row with the fastest time.
Note that the word SUB is used once in the total query, and twice in my explanation. This is only so it reads more easily, the uppermost(total) query is what you would actually type in your terminal.
Hope this is what you meant.
[EDIT]
This was my output by the way:
MariaDB [swimmers]> SELECT NAME, DISTANCE, STROKE_ID, TIME FROM (
SELECT NAME, DISTANCE, STROKE_ID, TIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
PARTITION BY DISTANCE, STROKE_ID ORDER BY TIME)
AS rn FROM testing) SUB WHERE rn = 1;
+------------------+----------+-----------+--------+
| NAME             | DISTANCE | STROKE_ID | TIME   |
+------------------+----------+-----------+--------+
| Susane Smith     |       50 |         1 |  74.33 |
| Susane Smith     |       50 |         2 |  83.23 |
| Charlotte Castle |       50 |         3 |  138.5 |
| Susane Smith     |      100 |         1 |  168.4 |
| Susane Smith     |      100 |         2 | 174.93 |
| Charlotte Castle |      100 |         3 |  349.2 |
| Charlotte Castle |      200 |         1 | 476.46 |
| Maddy Franks     |      200 |         2 | 377.15 |
| Charlotte Castle |      200 |         3 | 676.12 |
+------------------+----------+-----------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.001 sec)


I have now clue why the table wont render at the line with: |DISTANCE|STROKE_ID|nr|, it renders in the editor of SO but not here. No clue, but if you want you can just paste it in a markdown renderer. I added line breaks to it for readability bcuz well it wont render. EDIT Someone fixed it, thx, no clue what happened.

Thank you so very much for going the extra mile for me. I will try this the moment I get back to my desk.

DISTINCT ON makes this very simple:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (stroke_id, distance) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY stroke_id, distance, time;

Detailed explanation:

Select first row in each GROUP BY group?

Subtle detail: you seem to want to order by stroke_id first, hence the sort order in ORDER BY.
